# How to specify system path variables in WIndows CE 5.0?

Tags: path, windows-ce

I have a VS 2008 application on a specific path in windows CE that I want to be able to run from any directory. I read that Windows CE doesn't have traditional environment variable setting, and that it doesn't recognize relative paths. How do I set this up?

I read that you can define search paths in a registry but the examples I've seen either are used for executing something upon booting -- I just want something to be able to be run from any directory.

Comment: You can use 'Startup' folder. Just create some launcher (and put it into 'Startup' folder) which will run your app from any specific folder.